# How to calculate the total of each list, in a list of lists Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have collected a list of lists, each list representing data from a single day. I need to find the SUM of these to calculate the total volume each day. I can only seem to add together each list, not an individual lists data.

Provides the total of all the lists, not each individual lists total.

```
for ele in range(0, len(y_pred)): 
    total = total + y_pred[ele] 


print (total)
```

Expected 18 outputs, each lists sum, not one output with a sum of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use this pattern in Python:

```
for ele in range(0, len(y_pred)):  # let's not use "ele" as a var name, btw. confusing
    total = total + y_pred[ele]
```

because you can just write:

```
for element in y_pred: 
    total = total + element
```

Anyway, you could use `map` as another poster suggested, but the simplest way is to just extend your existing pattern. Since you have a list within a list, you have two lists to iterate through:

```
for sub_list in mega_list:
    for element in sub_list:
        total += element
```

Comment: All over the answers are amazing and worked perfectly so thank you everyone

Comment: but I am going to mark this one as the answer for providing the most information on how I can adjust my answer already and explaining why

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` and `sum`:

```
sums = list(map(sum, list_of_lists))
```

where `list_of_lists` is the list that contains other lists. Now, `sums` is a list containing the sum of each sub-list. To get the entire sum, use `sum` again with the new `sums` list:

```
sum(sums)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use sum.

```
[sum(x) for x in ll]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` in a `for` loop:

```
total = []   
for i in list_of_lists:
    total.append(sum(i))

print(total)
```